# Unable to define an Azure function mapped on the root content path /

Tags: azure-functions

My goal is to write an Azure function mapped directly to the root content path `/` with a custom response.

```
curl -v localhost:80 
...
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

I'm using Azure functions in a container context, disabled the default page via an environment variable in the Dockerfile. Also the routerprefix is set to an empty string. So the default `/api` prefix for all endpoints is disabled. The entire code is [here](https://github.com/KacperBak/azure-function-on-root-path).

My function class looks like this:

```
namespace RootMappedProject
{
    public static class MyRootMappedFunction
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// curl -v 127.0.0.1/Simple
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</returns>
        [FunctionName("Simple")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Simple(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Processing simple endpoint ...");
            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult("true");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// curl -v 127.0.0.1 should return 400 Status code
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>HTTP/1.1 204 No Content</returns>
        [FunctionName("Root")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Root(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Processing root endpoint, this is a bad request");
            return (ActionResult) new BadRequestObjectResult("false");
        }
    }
}
```

This causes the following NOT intended result:

```
curl -v localhost:80 
...
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
```

Is it possible to write a function mapping for the `/` path? 
Because neither "", "/" nor null are possible values to set as function names.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use proxies to achieve something like that --https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies

In your case, you could have a `proxies.json` in your function app root directory such that --

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "proxy1": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "methods": [ "GET", "POST" ],
                "route": "/"
            },
            "backendUri": "http://localhost:<port>/Simple"
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested your code with this. But I am sure this would work. You may need to modify the `"backendUri"` to match what you are looking for and where you've hosted it.